# Select records virtually between a range of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-insert

How can I select records between a range of date? For example, suppose that the start date is 9/1/2019 and the finish date is 9/5/2019. Then I want to select virtually records as follow:

My problem is that there is no table which saved the records.

```
Date    |Some Data
--------|---------
9/1/2019|Some Data
9/2/2019|Some Data
9/3/2019|Some Data
9/4/2019|Some Data
9/5/2019|Some Data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this below option with Recursive CTE-

```
DECLARE @start_date DATE= '2019-09-01', @end_date DATE= '2019-09-05';

WITH cte
AS 
(
    SELECT @start_date AS date_, 'Some Data' AS Val

    UNION ALL

    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, date_) AS DATE), 'Some Data' AS Val
    FROM cte
    WHERE date_ < @end_date
)

SELECT *
FROM cte OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Output is-

```
date_       Val
2019-09-01  Some Data
2019-09-02  Some Data
2019-09-03  Some Data
2019-09-04  Some Data
2019-09-05  Some Data
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the following query is verbatim what you described:

```
SELECT Date, [Some Data]
FROM yourTable
WHERE Date BETWEEN '20190901' AND '20190905';
```

But this of course assumes that such a table actually exists, and that you maintained a date column.

Comment: No, there is not a table such as 'yourTable' but I want to select records by giving two dates

Comment: Huh?  If there is no table, how can you select any data from it?

Comment: The problem is right there. So I want to know that is there any way to virtually create records?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this question by using a stored procedure:

- Create a Stored Procedure
- Create a virtual table with a column named Date
- Get Start Date and Finish Date and calculate DATEDIFF between dates
- Insert records using a loop to the table
- Perform a Select query from the virtually created table
- Drop virtually created table

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the recursive CTE is to use a tally/numbers table

```
DECLARE @start_date DATE= '2019-09-01', @end_date DATE= '2019-09-05';

; with NUMBERS AS ( -- replace with proper numbers/tally table
    select d.number from (values (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8)) as d(number)
)
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, number, @start_date) as [Date]
    , 'Some Data' as [Some Data]
FROM NUMBERS
WHERE NUMBER >= 0 AND NUMBER <= DATEDIFF(day, @start_date, @end_date)
```